# Помогите разобраться с Socket Сокетом

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Дело в том, что когда клиент подключается к серверу и передает несколько раз данные, то сервер ИНОГДА отображает, что будто клиент подключился к серверу за 1 подход 3-5 раз (то есть клиент нажал на кнопку 1 раз, а сервер говорит, что 5 раз).

[image: http://snag.gy/suSyj.jpg]

Код Java Server: http://pastebin.com/tkYtSW44

Код Android Java Client: http://pastebin.com/E5g3HjZ7

Дело простое. Нажал на кнопку, сказал слово. Данные переходят на сервер, а он сохраняет в файл. В итоге когда записываются файлы, то получается так.

```
0 файл норм\1 файл норм\ 2 файл норм\ (после происходит скачек с цифры 2 на 6)
3 файл норм\4 файл, крякоябры всякие\ 5 вообще цифры не понятные\ 6 пустота полная...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коде сервера есть несколько ошибок.

```
inputStream.read(buf);
```

Эта строка читает в буффер, но Вы абсолютно игнорируете количество байт, которое она читает. Соответственно, когда чуть ниже записываете данные

```
fileOutputStream.write(buf);
```

Вы записываете весь буффер. А прочитаться мог только один-два байта... Вот поэтому и мусор.

Правильно где-то так:

```
byte buf[] = new byte[size+100];
int bytes_read = inputStream.read(buf);
File file = new File("Files/asd"+a+".txt");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
fileOutputStream.write(buf, bytes_read);
fileOutputStream.close();
```

В клиенте такая же ошибка.

Бесконечный цикл в клиенте - это нечто. :)

```
while (true){

}
```

Не нужно понапрасну садить батарею пользователю.

Comment: Насчет клиента я уже сам про это понял...я сделал цикл думая что сокет закроеться после выбоплнения потока...а он оказывается будет работать.

Чем это строчка, отличается от этой
int bytes_read = inputStream.read(buf);
size=inputStream.available() ведь тут я и считываю сколько байтов доступно для чтения.
Да и к тому же fileOutputStream.write(buf, bytes_read); нет конструктора с 2 параметрами, где вы такой нашли то?)

Comment: Дело не в этом. Проблема в том, что передача из файла проходит нормально, а из диктофона плохо. Так что мне надо как-то прсоледить, что запись с диктофона закончилась, и после этого только передавать файл.

Comment: write - это не конструктор, это метод:). Да, там ноль совершенно случайно пропущен. Правильный метод [write](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(byte[], int, int)) имеет три аргумента.

Да, read прочитает доступные байты, но буфер у Вас на 100 байт больше. И эти 100 байт будут содержать мусор. Но, если честно, то документация намекает

> It is particularly important to realize that you must not use this method to size a container and assume that you can read the entirety of the stream without needing to resize the container.